# Add elements into an array when the element doesnt exist

Tags: c#, arrays

I habe a sentence:

```
    string x = "This is a first string, this is a second string.";
```

When add every word into an array

```
    string[] words = x.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' });
```

What do I have to do to add only unique words into the array ?

Answer (score 7):

Use Linq.

Also, since Split takes a params array, you don't need the new char[] part.

```
string[] words = x.Trim().Split(' ').Distinct().ToArray();
```

Comment: An answer with three upvotes in a full minute and SO decides not to tell me at all. Geez.

Comment: You might also want to use a regex or something similar to strip out any punctuation, so that you don't have one entry for "string," and one entry for "string.".

Comment: haha, you were faster ;) It's like: "Ladies and Gentlemen, start your engines!"

Comment: You'll also want to handle different casing of a word

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
string[] words = x.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do is:

```
string[] words = x.Trim().Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the string to array, you could traverse the array to see if word already exists.

For example:

```
List<string> arrayStr = new List<string>();
```

Before adding, you could do

```
if(arrayStr.Contains(abc))
MessageBox.Show("Word already exists");
else
arrayStr.Add(abc);
```

hope this helps